# Using Play for Scala, how do I read in JSON body {a=...,b=...,c...} from POST request?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a JSON body arriving in a `POST` request.  For simplicity sake, let's say it is:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}
```

How do I read those values into variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` in a Play controller, and what should the appropriate line in the routes file look like?

Comment: val a = (body \ "a").as[Long]

Comment: @andrey.ladniy: Did you mean .asInstanceOf ?  That worked.

Comment: No. If I understand properly, you want read values from json property. So `def as[T]` Tries to convert the node into a T, throwing an exception if it can't.

Comment: When I used just .as[...], the as was highlighted red.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Maybe a bit later.  My code is a bit of a mess at the moment, as I've been writing and rewriting.  I have another problem, my GET method returns Action[AnyContent] and works, but the docs I've read say the POST should do f() = Action {...}, and I'm struggling to resolve the difference between Action[AnyContent] and Action.  In both cases I read in four values, do some computation, and return a JSON result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109590/discussion-between-andrey-ladniy-and-gknauth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using JsValue.as/asOpt](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Using-JsValue.as/asOpt)

```
val a = (body \ "a").as[Long]
```